# Good Text Tokenizer Library

Tags: c, text

What is a good open source C word tokenizer library?

I am look for something like

```
Tokenize("there are three apples. One is orange, the other is blue,"
         " and, finally, the last is yellow!")
```

with the output not containing any punctuation.

Comment: What exactly is your expected/desired output?  How do you want the memory management done?  (That is, should the tokenizer allocate memory for you, or will you pass it a buffer into which it should copy tokens?  And what to do about overflows?  Note that `strtok()` modifies its input string, so passing a string literal to it is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: token into noun, verb and so on i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only need is to strip the punctuations, I'd use a `for` cycle that outputs (whatever it means in your context) the source string character by character, skipping the `ispunct()` ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [strtok](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtok.html), which is available in `string.h`.

Comment: On the given string - a string literal that is entitled to be placed in read-only memory - using `strtok()` is likely to give you a core dump or its moral equivalent.

Comment: @Jonathan, if you have a string constant, strdup() it first. That's not a big task.

Answer (score 0):

lex/flex is the classic tool, but it may be somewhat heavyweight for what you're doing.